# Slurm Cluster Python Script Not Running on Multiple Nodes using SBATCH

Tags: python, cluster-computing, slurm, feature-selection, mlxtend

We recently setup a Slurm Cluster with 2 Nodes(1 headnode+compute node and 1 compute nodes) for some HPC CFD simulations.Right now i am trying to run some python script which is used for feature selection in one of our Machine learning project which would run for around a day in one system.I have configured python and installed all libraries in 2 machines, verified Slurm node availability, configured job Script with required parameters(shown below) .But while trying to run the job using SBATCH, i am able to see the script execution in the head node where i run the SBATCH but not on the other node.the execution happens in the exact number of cores i specified in job script.however when i specify  the compute name in command using --nodelist , the script is running on the other compute node.
Kindly help as i am starter in both slurm cluster management as well as python.

**Python Script**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif, mutual_info_classif
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_sequential_feature_selection as plot_sfs
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('seaborn')
# df = pd.read_csv('vib_processed_data.csv')#Vibration
df = pd.read_csv('curr_processed_data.csv')#Current

# print(df.shape)
# print(df.describe().T.to_string())
meta = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=["mimb", "bbl", "mbl", "fcl", "file_name"],
                   header=None, skiprows=1)
# print(meta.shape)

meta_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(6):
    dummy = meta.copy()
    dummy["file_name"] = dummy["file_name"].apply(lambda x: f"{x}_{i}")
    meta_new = pd.concat([
        meta_new,
        dummy
    ])
# print(meta_new.head(), meta_new.shape)
meta = meta_new.reset_index(drop=True)

no_single_defects_df = pd.concat([meta.query('mimb==0&bbl==0&mbl==0&fcl==0'),
meta.query('(mimb==1 |mimb==2) &bbl==0&mbl==0&fcl==0'),
meta.query('mimb==0&(bbl==1|bbl==2)&mbl==0&fcl==0'),
meta.query('mimb==0&bbl==0&(mbl==1|mbl==2)&fcl==0'),
meta.query('mimb==0&bbl==0&mbl==0&(fcl==1|fcl==2)')]).reset_index(drop=True)

# print(no_single_defects_df.tail())
no_single_defects_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
defects = ['mimb', 'bbl', 'mbl', 'fcl']
labels = np.argmax(no_single_defects_df[defects].values, axis=1).tolist()
no_single_defects_df=pd.merge(no_single_defects_df, df, on="file_name", how="left")

f_values, p_values = f_classif(no_single_defects_df.drop(columns=defects+["file_name"]), labels)
anova_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=["features", "f_values", "p_values"])
anova_test["features"] = no_single_defects_df.drop(columns=defects+["file_name"]).columns
anova_test["f_values"] = f_values
anova_test["p_values"] = p_values
anova_test = anova_test.sort_values(by=["f_values", "p_values"], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
# print(anova_test.head(100).to_string())

features = anova_test[anova_test.index  < 100]["features"].values



# corr = df[features].corr()
# mask = np.triu(corr)
# plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
# sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask)
# plt.show()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import hamming_loss, multilabel_confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as sfs
from sklearn.metrics import get_scorer_names
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_sequential_feature_selection

from scipy.special import binom

def multinomial(params):
    if len(params) == 1:
        return 1
    return binom(sum(params), params[-1]) * multinomial(params[:-1])

for i in range(3):
    meta[f"Count_{i}"] = (meta[defects] == i).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
meta['groups'] = meta.apply(lambda row: int(multinomial([row['Count_0'],row['Count_1'], row['Count_2']])),axis=1)
# print(meta.shape)

df = pd.merge(meta, df, on="file_name", how = 'left')
train_data = df[features.tolist()+["groups"]+defects].reset_index(drop=True)
print(train_data.head())
Y = np.zeros((train_data.shape[0], 8))
counter = 0
for idx, defect in enumerate(defects):
    for i in range(1,3):
        Y[:,counter] = (train_data[defect].to_numpy() == i)
        counter += 1
# print(list(Y))
# print(train_data[defects].tail())
# print(np.sum(Y))
Y_str = []
for label in Y:
    Y_str.append("".join(list(map(str,label))))
# print(len(Y_str))
print('classification start')
gstrf = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=43)
# clf = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('lr', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))])
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LGBMClassifier())

feature_selector = sfs(
                estimator=clf,
                cv=list(
                        gstrf.split(df[features],y=Y_str, groups=df["groups"])
                        ),
                k_features=15,
                scoring='roc_auc',
                verbose=2,
                floating=True,
                n_jobs=-1
            )
feature_selector.fit(df[features], Y)
print(feature_selector.k_feature_names_)

selected_features = list(feature_selector.k_feature_names_)
# fig1 = plot_sequential_feature_selection(feature_selector.get_metric_dict(), figsize=(10,20))
# plt.ylim([0,1])
# plt.show()

dump_features_list = selected_features.copy()
dump_features_list.append('file_name')
for defect in defects:
    dump_features_list.append(defect)
dump_features_list.append('groups')

feature_dump = df[dump_features_list]
# feature_dump.to_csv("curr_feature_dump.csv", index=False)

# corr = df[list(feature_selector.k_feature_names_)].corr()
# mask = np.triu(corr)
# plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
# sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, annot=True);
# plt.show()

selected_features = list(feature_selector.k_feature_names_)

plt.rc('font', size=5)
fig,ax = plot_sfs(feature_selector.get_metric_dict(), kind='std_dev',
                figsize=(10, 7));
# ax.set_xticklabels(list(feature_selector.k_feature_names_))
plt.ylim(0,1)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=5)
ax.set_xlabel("Sequential Features")
ax.set_ylabel("Performance - AUC")
fig.align_labels()
plt.show()
fig.savefig("./vib_feature_selection_lgbm.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

train_1_indices = list(train_data.query("groups==1|groups==4|groups==6").index)
val_1_indices = list(set(train_data.index) - set(train_1_indices))
train_2_indices = list(train_data.query("groups==1|groups==12").index)
val_2_indices = list(set(train_data.index) - set(train_2_indices))

cv = [
    (train_1_indices, val_1_indices),
    (train_2_indices, val_2_indices),
    (val_1_indices, train_1_indices),
    (val_2_indices, train_2_indices),
]

# ps = PredefinedSplit(train_data["groups"])
# train_data["kfold"] = -1
# for fold, (train_indices, val_indices) in enumerate(cv):
#     train_data.loc[val_indices, "kfold"] = fold
# train_data[selected_features].head()

for fold, (train_indices, val_indices) in enumerate(cv):
    print(f"FOLD {fold}:\n")

    # splitting train and val based on k-fold
    x_train = train_data.loc[train_indices]
    x_val = train_data.loc[val_indices]

    print(f"train_groups: {x_train.groups.unique()}")
    print(f"val_groups: {x_val.groups.unique()}")

    # exclude 'group'
    x_train = x_train[selected_features]
    x_val = x_val[selected_features]

    y_train = Y[x_train.index]
    y_val = Y[x_val.index]

    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LGBMClassifier())

    #     clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LGBMClassifier(boosting_type="dart",
    #                                              objective="binary",
    #                                             verbose=-1))
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

    # predict train and val
    train_preds = clf.predict(x_train)
    val_preds = clf.predict(x_val)

    # calculate train and val loss (hamming)
    train_loss = hamming_loss(y_train, train_preds)
    val_loss = hamming_loss(y_val, val_preds)

    print(f"TRAIN LOSS: {train_loss}")
    print(f"OOF LOSS: {val_loss}\n")
    print(classification_report(y_val, val_preds))
    cMat = multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_val, val_preds)
    print(cMat)
    print("\n")
```

**Job Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=testjob
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=32
#SBATCH --nodes-per-node=16
#SBATCH --partition=accel_ai

python3 featureselector.py
```

i have tried running the script specifying srun/mpirun python3 in job script which runs the jobs in both nodes but the same script is being run in all cores as different instances as i understood from the job script which is not what i wanted.

Comment: A quick overview of your python code tells me that you are not managing any kind of parallelism there. You should code your python script to handle the calculus amongst multiple nodes (intra-node parallelism can be more easily obtained, even without expliciting if the library allows it, but inter-node parallelism... that's another beast).

Comment: any quick idea to impliment parallelism..is it with the multiprocessing library.can it be implemented on the sequential feature selector of mlextend library? also if it doesnot support parallelism, how can i see the python task taking up the desired --ntask-per-node number of cores i specify(even in single machine)?

Comment: No quick way to implement parallelism. You have to rearchitect your code with parallelism in mind to partition data as desired, merge it back and send all the data pieces between the different nodes. Take a look at mpi4py or any other MPI library for python. Also, switching to a different framework like Dask could help, it would be another way, maybe easier than the raw MPI approach.

Comment: To check which python processes you have running in your machine, you can use `ps` on the machine where the job is running. My bet is that you will only see one, as you are starting the interpreter as-is.

Comment: as you suggested i have run some test programs using dask scheduler but still im confused how it might work with specifically the feature selector part..since already the feature selector have parallelism implemented(n_jobs parameter) , wrapping all the code inside a function and running using dask schedules it to specified nodes? or will the same code will be running multiple instances? kindly help

Comment: BTW, #SBATCH --nodes-per-node=16 must be a typo of #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node.

Comment: ya sorry for that..i meant --ntasks-per-node only